# when inserting date and time in datetime column in mysql database it will insert date but time is 00-00-00

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

PreparedStatement   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into organisation (org_id,name,description,logo,created_date,created_by,is_status) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
pstmt.setString(2, name);
pstmt.setString(3, description);
pstmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));

int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: use Timestamp instead of date

Answer (score 2):

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) of `java.sql.Date`:

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify
>   this as an SQL DATE value.

If you see the date type only repesents the date not the time part. 
You have to use `java.sql.Timestamp`. Here is teh [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

> thin wrapper around java.util.Date that allows the JDBC API to
>   identify this as an SQL TIMESTAMP value

So your code should look like:

```
pstmt.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```